# python 2.7 breaking strings and calculate avg

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, extract

Using this code I have to get the result of PSI : 101-121 (Unhealthy). I need the value of 101 and 121 from var_psi to calculate average. Is there anyone that knows how to extract the 101 and 121 that can guide me along ? Thanks in advance =)

```
import xml.dom.minidom, xml.sax.saxutils
import logging
import httplib
from socket import timeout
import datetime
import time
import urllib2
import sys, os, platform, re
import sched, time
import simplejson as json
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom
from urllib2 import urlopen

var_xml = urlopen("http://app2.nea.gov.sg/data/rss/nea_psi.xml")
var_all = xml.dom.minidom.parse(var_xml)

def extract_content(var_all, var_tag, var_loop_count):
    return var_all.firstChild.getElementsByTagName(var_tag)[var_loop_count].firstChild.data

var_loop_count = 0
var_item = " "
while len(var_item) > 0:
    var_title = extract_content(var_all, "title", var_loop_count)
    var_date = extract_content(var_all, "pubDate", var_loop_count)
    var_psi = extract_content(var_all, "psi", var_loop_count)
    var_psi1= extract_content(var_all, "psi", var_loop_count)


    print var_psi

    var_loop_count += 1
    break

    try:
        var_item = var_all.firstChild.getElementsByTagName("item")[var_loop_count].firstChild.data
    except:      
        var_item = ""
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to extract content from an xml using python. There are a lot of informations out there on how to do it. http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml 
Using something like XPath should help extracting simple values like the one you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re

psi_values = re.compile(r'PSI.*?(\d+)-(\d+)')

psi_low, psi_high = psi_values.search(var_psi).groups()
```

If you need the values to be integers, use `map(int, ...)` to apply the `int()` function to each matched group:

```
psi_low, psi_high = map(int, psi_values.search(var_psi).groups())
```

For your code sample, that gives me:

```
>>> psi_low, psi_high
(101, 121)
```

Comment: May I ask something, my psi low returns 1, psi high returns 121. Is there any problem ? Sorry I am a noob to python.

Comment: @KaiLun: No, that's my fault; updated the expression, a `?` was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `re` module for that:

```
>>> import re
>>> test_string = '101-121 (Unhealthy)'
>>> psi_re = re.compile(r'(\d+)-(\d+) \(Unhealthy\)')
>>> psi_re.match(test_string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb23140>
>>> psi_re.match(test_string).groups()
('101', '121')
```